# Issue with pointers and postfixes

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, array-indexing

So I have to find out why specific values are printed out, and I've solved most of it but, I've got a problem with the last three.

I'd be happy for any help

```
int main(void)
{
    int myValues[] = { 9, 0, 12345, 1, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5, 4 };
    mess(&myValues[3]); //starts function mess
}

void mess(int *n)
{
    printf("mess :%d\n", *n++); //prints value of 3rd index (1) and sets pointer to fourth index
    printf("mess: %d\n", *++n); //sets n to 5th index and prints its value
    printf("mess: %d\n", -2[n]); //value: -3
    printf("mess: %d\n", (-2)[n]); //value: 1
    printf("mess: %d\n", n[-6]); //value: 32766
}
```

I just don't understand how the values -3, 1 and 32766 come to be

Comment: Where this code is from?  Run away.

Comment: `a[n]` is the same as `*(a + n)`. Fill in the blanks and you get your result.

Comment: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/joke.html

Comment: @EugeneSh. We learn by doing. Nothing to be scared of.

Comment: @nicomp I am scared of institutions giving students exercises which are teaching wrong things.

Comment: @EugeneSh. You don't know the context. I give my students code with gotos, one-letter variable names, incorrect comments, and many other negative examples. It's part of the learning process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let's visualize the memory pointed to by `n`, after the execution of first two `printf()` statements:

```
int myValues[] = { 9, 0, 12345, 1, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5, 4 };
                                      ^
                                   // n
```

Let's see one by one

- **Statement 1:**       `printf("mess: %d\n", -2[n]); //value: -3`

  [Check the operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). `-2[n]` is parsed as `-(2[n])`. Thus, the `-` is the sign, `2[n]` is the same as `n[2]` which is the value `3`. Thus, the statement is the same as

  ```
  printf("mess: %d\n", -(n[2]) );
  ```

  ***Visualization:***

  ```
   int myValues[] = { 9, 0, 12345, 1, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5, 4 };
                                         ^     ^^
                                      // n     n+2
  ```
- **Statement 2:** `printf("mess: %d\n", (-2)[n]); //value: 1`

  Here, `n[-2]` is the same as `*(n-2)`. Result is the value at that index. (Check the above visualization).

  ***Visualization:***

  ```
   int myValues[] = { 9, 0, 12345, 1, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5, 4 };
                                   ^     ^    ^
                        //        n-2    n   n+2
  ```
- Finally, **Statement 3:** `printf("mess: %d\n", n[-6]); //value: 32766`

  As per the current content of the pointer `n`, the least accessible index is `-5`, attempting to access the memory location at an index `-6` is accessing out of bounds, causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). The result cannot be justified.

  ***Visualization:***

  ```
   int myValues[] =      { 9, 0, 12345, 1, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5, 4 };
                    ???    ^                  ^
         //         n-6   n-5                 n
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Makes it a lot more unerstandable

Answer (score 4):

```
printf("mess: %d\n", -2[n]); //value: -3
```

`-2[n]` is `-(n[2])` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/381549/10411602) for an explanation on this quirk). At this point, `n[2]` gets you `3` so `-n[2]` is `-3`.

```
printf("mess: %d\n", (-2)[n]); //value: 1
```

This is `[-2]`, which means 2 to the "left" of where you started out, which result in `1`.

```
printf("mess: %d\n", n[-6]); //value: 32766
```

This goes to *before* the start of your array, and that's undefined behavior. It could do *anything*, but most likely it just prints some rubbish value by interpreting memory that it shouldn't access this way.

I'm not sure about how well defined the other statements of the code are. It's really bad practice, please don't write code like this. As you aptly put, it's a `mess`.

Comment: well it's not my code, just some code from our prof. to see how deep our theoretical understanding to this subject is.... But still thanks your answer helps a lot!

Answer (score 3):

First, remember that in C, array indexing is commutative - `a[i]` and `i[a]` yield the same result.

So, the line

```
printf("mess: %d\n", -2[n]); //value: -3
```

is equivalent to writing

```
printf( "mess: %d\n", -n[2] );
```

The postfix `[]` operator has higher precedence than the unary `-` operator, so the expression `-2[n]` is parsed as `-(2[n])`.  You're indexing 2 elements from `n` (3), and negating the result.

In the following line,

```
printf("mess: %d\n", (-2)[n]); //value: 1
```

the expression `(-2)[n]` is equivalent to `n[-2]` - you're indexing 2 elements *before* `n`, which gives you 1.

In the line

```
printf("mess: %d\n", n[-6]); //value: 32766
```

you're trying to index 6 elements before `n`; unfortunately, that's outside the bounds of your array.  At this point the behavior is undefined.  You could get garbage output, your code code crash, or something else could happen.